# Pong Game via Javascript: Player Paddle to remain within the Canvas Area

Tags: javascript, canvas, p5.js, pong, paddle-paddle

I am teaching kids about the basic and simplest way of designing and coding the Pong Game via Javascript in the p5 editor.
I just have a question regarding the initial phase of designing.

The code is as follows:

```js
function setup()

{
    createCanvas(400,400);
}

function draw()

{
    background('black');
    rect(20,160,10,80);
    rect(195,195,10,10);
    rect(380,mouseY,10,80);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.0.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

The first rect function is for the computer paddle controlled by AI. The second rect function is for the ball. The third rect function is for the player paddle.

I am using mouseY for the vertical movement but the paddle is going out of the canvas of dimension 400*400 towards the lower part of the canvas.

Without using any function and via simple addition/subtraction of the various numerical coordinates involved in this code, how can I prevent the player paddle from moving out of the canvas?

Answer (score 1):

You have to limit the y coordinate of the paddle to the range [0, height-80]. [`height`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/height) is a built in variable containing the height of the canvas and the height of the paddle is 80.

```js
function setup() {
    createCanvas(400,400);
}

function draw() {
    background('black');
    rect(20,160,10,80);
    rect(195,195,10,10);

    let y = mouseY;
    if (y < 0)
        y = 0;
    if (y+80 > height)
        y = height-80;
    rect(380,y,10,80);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.0.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

This can be further improved by using [`min`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/min) and [`max`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/max):

```js
function setup() {
    createCanvas(400,400);
}

function draw() {
    background('black');
    rect(20,160,10,80);
    rect(195,195,10,10);

    let y = max(0, min(height-80, mouseY));
    rect(380,y,10,80);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.0.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```